# finding element by title in sortable - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I´m coding two panel of sortable element that connect to each other. In one of them, i put searching input to find what still there by matching their title to on keyup processes...

this is my code

```
$('#search-nama').keyup(function(){
        var find = new RegExp($('#search-nama').val().toUpperCase());

        grup_mk = $('#makul-container').find('.grup-mk');
        //grup_mk = $('.grup-mk');
        $.each(grup_mk,function(i, l){
            console.log ($(this).attr("title"));
            s = $(this).attr("title").toString().toUpperCase();
            if(find.test(s)){
                $(this).show();
            }else{
                $(this).hide();
            }
        })
    });
```

this function ussualy not working. the console show me this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
```

Comment: you sure every `.grup-mk` has a `title` attribute?

Comment: plus you miss a `var` of your `grup_mk`. plus plus, you'd better use camelCase for you js variable. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the attribute is undefined:

eg:

```
if ( typeof $(this).attr("title") !== 'undefined' ) {
  // Do Stuff
}
else {
  // Do Something else
}
```